# How can I check the spelling in plain text files in eclipse c/c++ edition?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Luna Release (4.4.0).
I enabled the spell checking (Preferences: General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling: Enable Spell Checking) and I'm using a user defined dictionary.

The spell checking works perfect in C/C++ source files but I am puzzled how to do the spell checking of texts in plain text files.
There is no automatical spell check or options like "Do spell check" in the context menu or in the main menu.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have all of the settings enabled under Spelling?

Comment: All options except "Ignore string literals" are enabled. Even if I disable all "Ignore" options, nothing changes, i. e. no spell checking happens in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is still open, a workaround:

I am having a similar problem with getting the Eclipse Luna CDT C/C+ spell-checking engine to handle standalone *.dox files (no problem with inline Doxygen comments within source files).

The only workaround I could find (http://thomasplagwitz.com/2015/03/02/getting-eclipse-cdt-to-spell-check-non-source-files/) was renaming my *.dox files to something that the spell checker seems to consider relevant, like *.dox.cpp.

Hth